# fastlane firebase_app_distribution get download url

Tags: fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I'm uploading my apk to firebase using fastlane
using this code:

```
result = firebase_app_distribution(
            app: app,
            firebase_cli_token: firebase_cli_token,
            android_artifact_path: file,
            release_notes: releaseNotes
)
```

result is HASH that can be translated to a json containing the download url.
How can I parse the result to this download url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's easier then I thought, to get the download url:

```
download_url = result[:testingUri]
```